# React Navigation - Pass props into Navigator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

My React Native app has several conditions in which it needs to handle deep links when the user clicks on a link for an invite. My intent was to setup the Link listeners in the main app.js file and when a deep link is detected I need to pass the data into the Splash view to determine several factors before adding the user to the group they are invited to.

I am using React Navigation. I initially tried to use redux by updating the store with the url data but ran into timing issues as the Splash page was loading before redux was updated. So I have attempted to create an HOC wrapper for the Navigator as follows:

***HOC Linker:***

```
import * as React from "react";

const Linker = (Component) => {
    return ({ children, ...props }) => {
        return (
            <Component { ...props }>
                { children }
            </Component>
        );
    }
};

export default Linker;
```

In my App JS file I import the Linker and wrap the main navigator with the HOC component. I then add a prop that is updated when React Native Linking method detects a deep link. It updates state with the parameters.

***App JS:***

```
import Navigator from './ui/navigation/navigator';
const LinkerWrapper = Linker(Navigator);

render() {
    return (
        <LinkerWrapper linking={this.state.url} />
    );
}
```

My Navigator file looks as follows:

***Navigator:***

```
import { createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import Splash from '../screens/splash/splash';

import AuthStack from './auth';
import AppStack from './app';

const Navigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  Loading: Splash,
  Auth: AuthStack,
  App: AppStack
});

export default Navigator;
```

When I click on a deep link the app opens as expected, I parse the url and prep the data object, state is updated and the splash page is re rendered as expected, the props are passed through the HOC, but when the componentWillReceiveProps method is ran in the Splash page I do not see any props from the linking prop.

[image]

I have tried many different things. I am really new to react so I know I am probably doing something fundamentally wrong. I am guessing I am missing something with React Navigation. One of the things I tried was to change the screen value to a function passing in the props. I was hoping that would magically make the linking prop appear in the Splash page props. Below was my attempt:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import Splash from '../screens/splash/splash';

import AuthStack from './auth';
import AppStack from './app';

const Navigator = createSwitchNavigator({
    Loading: {
        screen: props => <Splash { ...props }/>
    },
    Auth: AuthStack,
    App: AppStack
});

export default Navigator;
```

Unfortunately that didn't work. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks.